# parameter passing to python3.x script from commandline

Tags: python

i am very new to python.
i would like to write a script where if i didn't pass any value to an argument, it should ask value for that argument. if passed, it should pick that value and continue.passing these values are from command line.
i tried below code and python is throwing error saying variable is not initialized.

```
if (fileName == None)
    fileName == "C:\\filename"
print(fileName)
```

command line call for executing the script:- script.py "C:\filename"

Stack trace :-
    if(NO_ERROR == None)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: small question, can i use name value pairs also for the same,           
 Ex:- script.py fileName="C:\filename" just like in command line. this is my actual requirement. i can accomplish this in javascript. i would like to use the same way in python also. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sys module provides lots of options to play with command line arguments.
below example might be helpful to you.

```
import sys
#storing the argument in string
st=" ".join(sys.argv)
#splitting the list to get the file name and storing it in list
var=st.split('=')
if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print "Enter Argument\n"
else:
    print 'Argument found'
    print var[1]
```

Comment: small question, can i use name value pairs also for the same, Ex:- script.py fileName="C:\filename" just like in command line. this is my actual requirement. i can accomplish this in javascript. i would like to use the same way in python also. is it possible?

Comment: Check it now , this should work

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon at the end of the if statement

```
if (fileName == None):
   fileName = "C:\\filename"
print(fileName)
```

Comment: Sorry, noticed that the 2nd line is also not syntactically right. Assignment uses only a single '='.

Comment: also brackets in 1 line are redundant